# ssh localhost without password doesn't work on Fedora 14

Tags: ssh, fedora, rhel

I performed:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

then in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` changed `StrictModes` to `no` and restarted sshd.

And I have:

```
$ ssh localhost
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
dev@localhost's password:
```

What's wrong? How to make `ssh localhost` working without password?

UPDATE:

```
$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_5.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e-fips 6 Sep 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/dev/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/dev/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/dev/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 434
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Try running `ssh -v localhost` and paste here the output. Plus look for messages from sshd in `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: No /var/log/syslog|auth.log files on my system. /var/log/messages do not contain anything on this.

Comment: Does either `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0 ssh localhost` or `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` work?

Comment: Btw. does it help to logout and login again? Maybe your ssh-agent behaves strangely?

Comment: 'ssh -vv localhost' will show the actual key exchange attempt. That may be helpful.

Comment: For fun, kill all 'ssh-agent' processes, restart 'ssh-agent -s', and then run 'ssh-add'.

Comment: I changed it to

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and it worked. I.e. dsa->rsa. I don't have idea why it doesn't work with dsa

Comment: FWIW, I always use two commands: 1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa` (or `dsa`), then 2. `ssh-copy-id "username@hostname -p"` for rsa.  I don't usually use dsa, but I think the second command is something like `ssh-copy-id -i /homedirectory/.ssh/id_dsa username@hostname -p`.

Comment: Check the permissions on $HOME/.ssh and the key files.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the permissions on the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and the `~/.ssh/` folder:

```
chmod go-w $HOME/.ssh
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown `whoami` $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Source: http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14

Comment: Welcome to *nix SX. Although your answer is OK, please note that the permissions on `~/.ssh` and its files are the problem has been suggested to be the cause of the problem in comments as well (James Youngman). It is good practise (IMHO) that if you improve on someones comment or answer, you give some credit in yours.

Answer (score 0):

Check SELinux passible issue in my case I had to

```
ausearch -c 'sshd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sshd
semodule -i my-sshd.pp
/sbin/restorecon -v /home/xxxxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score -4):

Add your public key to the authorized_keys.

Comment: That was "`cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`"